# How to pass an argument when calling a view file?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I wrote a webform using Sinatra and Haml that will be used to call a Ruby script.

Everything seems fine except for one thing: I need to pass an argument to a Haml view file from the Sinatra/Ruby script.

Here is a part of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'

get '/' do
  haml :index
end

post '/' do
  name = params[:name]
  vlan = params[:vlan]

  tmp = nil
  tmp = %x[./wco-hosts.rb -a -n #{name} -v #{vlan}]

  if tmp.include?("Error")
    haml :fail
  else
    haml :success
  end
end
```

If the script encounters an arror it will return a string including the word "Error". If this happens, I'm calling a Haml file which will show an error page to the users.  If the script doesn't encounter an arror, it will return a success page.

I want to include, in the success/fail page, the name of the new VM the user added. My problem is that I have no clue how to pass it in both my Haml files. I searched for a solution, but did not find anything.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can pass a hash of parameters to the Haml method using the `:locals` key:

```
get '/' do
    haml :index, :locals => {:some_object => some_object}
end
```

This way the Ruby code in your Haml file can access `some_object` and render whatever content is in there, call methods etc.

Comment: Will this work for a layout too? If i have `haml :index, :layout => :common_layout, :locals => { :object => my_object }`, will the `object` local variable be defined in the `common_layout` template?

Answer (score 7):

Haml supports passing variables as locals. With Sinatra, you can send these locals like so:

```
haml :fail, :locals => {:vm_name => name}
```

and in the view, reference the variable using `locals[:vm_name]` or simply `vm_name`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm doing this in Sinatra+Markaby, I think it should be the same with Haml:

In Ruby script: `@var = 'foo'`

In template: `User name: #{@var}`

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
haml(template, options = {}, locals = {})
```

I'd try

```
haml :success, {}, {my_var: my_value}
```